# Should i use ninject to initialize service with repository?

Tags: c#, ninject

I have class which have :

```
IMessageRepository messageRepository;
IMessageService messageService;
```

Should i put both of them in constructor of the class and because of that use ninject to initialize both of them ?

```
public MessageController(IMessageRepository messageRepository, IMessageService messageService)
    {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
        this.messageService = messageService;
    }
```

Or should i take only messageRepository from ninject and initialize my messageService with it? (It takes IMessageRepository in constructor)

```
public MessageController(IMessageRepository messageRepository)
    {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
        this.messageService = new MessageService(messageRepository);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to put both of them in constructor parameters.

Because, in future, you might have another realization of `IMessageRepository`.

Moreover, you will have more control over your dependencies outside of your classes (e.g. you might need to use different repositories in `Controller` and `Service`).

Hope it will help.